# managed beans not instantiated with embedded tomcat 7

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, tomcat

I have a fairly small JSF 2 application using myfaces and primefaces. It is setup as a as a tomcat 7 service in Eclipse and works fine, including ajax and the works.

However, I want to unit test it, so I've added Tomcat 7 as a test dependency and create the appropriate startup code.

```
// create tomcat
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(HTTP_PORT);

// add "web" as a webapp, all classes that are in the current classpath (all in eclipse) are available
Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("/" + CONTEXT_PREFIX, new File("src/main/webapp").getAbsolutePath());

// start the server (but do not wait)
tomcat.start();
```

This also starts correctly, but the managed beans are not loaded. So even though the pages look good, there is no behavior. The problems seems to be similar to this Jetty blog, talking about how Jetty only searches for managed beans in a certain location.

http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com.au/2009/12/running-jsf-2-on-embedded-jetty.html

The web deployment assembly in Eclipse for the Tomcat server has it place all the class files in WEB-INF/classes, so that probably is the problem.

Is it possible for embedded Tomcat 7 to use addWebapp (in order to unit test the web.xml) but redirect WEB-INF/classes to the correct directory?

Comment: Which server you were using for development?

Comment: Exactly the same version, but that is not relevant in a unittest. BTW, I have "patched" the setup; by having Eclipse write the classes directly into WEB-INF/classes. But compiling into the source tree is a bad idea ofcourse, so I still need to be able to have WEB-INF/classes point to Eclipse's build directory.